# How to put items in dynamodb using c# lambda functions using AWSSDK.Dynamodbv2 using serverless framework

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, serverless-framework

I'm trying to write a lambda function which does CRUD operations on DynamoDB using serverless framework in C#.

I downloaded a nuget package and used putitem, getitems functions but in cloudwatch the error was like "no credential file found". I added roles in my serverless.yml file why do I need to add credentials again? I really want this solution in C#. I used boto3 for python, it never asked for aws credentials in code other than roles.

```
iamRoleStatements:
    - Effect: Allow
      Action: # Gives permission to DynamoDB tables in a specific region
        - dynamodb:Query
        - dynamodb:Scan
        - dynamodb:GetItem
        - dynamodb:PutItem
        - dynamodb:UpdateItem
        - dynamodb:DescribeTable
        - dynamodb:DeleteItem
      Resource: "arn:aws:dynamodb:${opt:region, self:provider.region}:${self:provider.environment.aws_account_id}:table/${self:provider.environment.dynamodb_table}"
```

Comment: The error *was* "no credential file found" or the error was *like* "no credential file found"? Also, go to the Lambda console and check the role associated with your Lambda function. Is it correct? Is the underlying policy for that IAM role correct in terms of DynamoDB permissions?

Comment: This is the exact exception
Unable to find credentials

Exception 1 of 4:
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'. The system cannot find the file specified.

I have set the permissions correctly but it searching for environment variables for access and secret keys

Comment: You mentioned that you're using a nuget package. Which one? Note that AWS also provides a .Net SDK that you can use and, like boto3, it will pick up credentials seamlessly from your Lambda's IAM role.